# How to export vector layer containing symbology compatible with ArcGIS on PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, pyqgis, symbology, vector-layer

I export vector layer(.shp) with symbology file(.qml) like below code.

The exported files works on QGIS, but on ArcMap (ArcGIS), qml file doesn't work.

How can I extract symbology file on PyQGIS so that it can also be used in ArcGIS?

```
symbol = layer.renderer().symbol()


symbol.setColor(QColor.fromRgb(255,5,0))

symbol.symbolLayer(0).setShape(QgsSimpleMarkerSymbolLayerBase.Arrow)
symbol.symbolLayer(0).setStrokeStyle(Qt.PenStyle(Qt.NoPen))

layer.triggerRepaint()

layer.saveNamedStyle(outputPath + '.qml')
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, outputPath + '.shp', "UTF-8", QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(coordinate), 'ESRI Shapefile',symbologyExport = QgsVectorFileWriter.FeatureSymbology)
```

Comment: The format of a layer file is different and AFAIK QGIS symbology isn't supported in ArcGIS (Desktop or Pro). You could lodge an enhancement request with Esri https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-survey123-questions/how-to-lodge-an-enhancement-request/td-p/798392 but I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: There is at least one utility to conver QML to LYRX, but I'm not aware of any that do it the other way around.